# Types of Characters used in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I am new to python and trying to get better at it.I have very little experience in Programming.
What is the best way to know which characters are used for a function.
Example:what is the difference between  (, {, [ .Why I have to use the different brackets.Is there any place where I can learn the very small detail also in Python. 
Your Help is highly appreciated.
Thanks all

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics Or https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Your question is not really valid for StackOverflow. You should really only ask questions on here if you have a specific problem with specific code. If you are trying to learn something this basic, I'd recommend searching for python tutorials and such. The documentation is also handy for things like this. Still, the point of StackOverflow isn't to help find information like this for people that could easily be found using a search engine.

Comment: They are for expressing data structures that are what would usually be called "arrays" in other language. Python has very different kinds. Look for things like "dictionaries", "sequences", "tuples", "stacks" and "lists": https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html.

Answer (score 1):

() are for tuples.
{} are for dictionaries.
[] are for lists.
You have to use different brackets because they are different data types.
You can learn Python with the python website:
[Python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/)

Comment: _"{} are for dictionaries"_ - That's not completely true. [`{}`'s are also used for `set()`s](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 1):

(, ) typically denotes tuples

```
>>>my_tuple = (1,2)
>>>my_tuple
(1,2)
```

[ ] typically denotes lists and indices

```
>>>my_list = [1,2]
>>>print my_list[1]
2
print my_tuple[0]
1
```

{ } are typically used for dictionaries (like JSON in javascript) and sets

```
>>>my_dict = { 'key_1':'value_1', 'key_2':'value_2' }
>>>my_set = { 1,1,2,2,3 }
>>>my_dict['key_1']
value_1
>>>my_set
{2,3,1}
```

i should note that that may not be the correct output for my_set, since sets remove duplicates and store them without order.

read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html